# Problem with regex, how do I get all with \S up until a special character?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Ive got the text:

```
192.168.20.31 Url=/flash/56553550_hi.mp4?token=(uniquePlayerReference=81781956||videoId=1)
```

And im trying to get the uniquePlayerReference and the videoId

Ive tried this regular expression:

```
(?<=uniquePlayerReference=)\S*
```

but it matches:

```
81781956||videoId=1)
```

And then I try and get the video id with this:

```
(?<=videoId=)\S*
```

But it matches the ) after the videoId.

My question is two fold:

1) How do I use the \S character and get it to stop at a character? (essentially what is the regex to do what i want) I cant get it to stop at a defined character, I think I need to use a positive lookahead to match but not include the double pipe).

2) When should I use brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ID isn't just digits then you could use `[^|]` instead of `\S`, i.e.

```
(?<=uniquePlayerReference=)[^|]*
```

Then you can use

```
(?<=videoId=)[^)]*
```

For the video ID

Comment: This is a really good response, i see what you have done, its says match any number of characters up until where it doesnt=|, genius!

Comment: @Pete2k: Not so much genius as a reasonable solution without full specs. If the IDs are always numbers then @annakata's solution below is more elegant.

Comment: lol okay mate, they arent always numbers so ill use yours as the answer in this case although i have marked them all as helpful as they have all taught me something i didnt know!

Answer (score 2):

Given that both id's are numeric you are probably better off using `\d` instead of `\S`. `\d` only matches numeric digits whereas `\S` matches any non-whitespace character.

What you might also do is a non gready match up till the character you do not want to match like so:

```
uniquePlayerReference=(.*?)\|\|videoId=(.*?)\)
```

Note that I have escaped both the `|` and `)` characters because otherwise they would have a special meaning inside a regex.

In C# you would use this like so: (which also answers your question what the brackets are for, they are meant to capture parts of the matched result).

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"uniquePlayerReference=(.*?)\|\|videoId=(.*?)\)");
Match match = regex.Match(
    "192.168.20.31 Url=/flash/56553550_hi.mp4?token=(uniquePlayerReference=81781956||videoId=1)");

if (match.Success)
{
    string playerReference = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string videoId = match.Groups[2].Value;
    // Etc.
}
```

Comment: thats a great response and works, however in my quest to become proficient can anybody do a solution where it would match up to the || regardless of what the values were? (unless a double pope was in it of course) :-)

Comment: This won't work, the `.*` is a greedy match and will read the rest of the string quite happily. You'd need to replace `.*` with `.*?` to make it non-greedy, then it would stop when it met the next character, `|` (doesn't need escaping).

Comment: @Lazarus: You are right. I was to fast in editing my solution. I have changed it back to what it was before.

Comment: No, leave your solution... just edit it ;) It's still a good answer.

Comment: @Lazarus: Changed my solution as per your suggestion :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the mul;tiplicity operator you have here - the `*` - which means "as many as possible". If you have an explicit number in mind you can use the operator `{a,b}` where a is a minimum and b a maximum number fo matches, but if you have an unknown number, you can't use \S (which is too generic).

As for brackets, if you mean `()` you use them to capture a part of a match for backreferencing. Bit complicated, think you need to use a [reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for that.

I think you want something like this:

```
/uniquePlayerReference=(\d+)||videoId=(\d+)/i
```

and then backreference to \1 and \2 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The \S means it matches any non-whitespace character, including the closing parenthesis. So if you had to use \S, you would have to explicitly say stop at the closing parenthesis, like this:

```
videoId=(\S+)\)
```

Therefore, you are better off using the \d, since what you are looking for are numeric:

```
uniquePlayerReference=(\d+)
videoId=(\d+)
```